# Java Remove from set causes IllegalStateException

Tags: java, set, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to remove, for example, the second element, which the program is giving to me.

But it causes for IllegalStateException.

What am I doing wrong?

```
HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<>();
list.add("123");
list.add("qwe");
list.add("asd");
int count = 0;
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  if (count == 1) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `iterator.remove()` without calling `iterator.next()` first. And besides that, without advancing the iterator with `iterator.next()`, your loop is an infinite loop.

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  String str = iterator.next();
  if (count == 1) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is true my bad, I think I need coffee sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+, here is Another way to remove from a `HashSet` without `Iterator`, you can use `removeIf` with an `AtomicInteger` like so :

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
int indexToRemove = 1;
list.removeIf(i -> count.getAndIncrement() == indexToRemove);
```

If the `indexToRemove` equal to 1 the result is : `[123, qwe]`